# Estoy haciendo un programa para sumar dos números pero los resultados que arroja son incorrectos

Tags: c++

Este es un pequeño programa para sumar dos números, todo funciona bien excepto la suma, ya que me da unos resultados loquísimos. ej 2+3=48874. La cosa es peor cuando no especifíco el short

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
int main() {


bool cont=true ;
char seguir;
short int n1;
short int n2;
//char op;
int res=n1+n2;

while(cont){
    cout<<"Ingrese un número"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    
    cout<<"Ingrese otro número"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;
    cout<<"El resultado es: "<<res<<endl;
    cout<<"¿Realizar otra suma?..."<<endl;
    cin>>seguir;
    if (seguir=='s'){
        cont=true;
    }else{
        cont=false;
    }
}
cout<<"¡Hasta pronto!";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Claro que te da un resultado loquísimo, estás sumando `int res=n1+n2;` antes de leer los números. Los programas se ejecutan linealmente, la suma una vez calculada no se retrocalcula al leer `n1` y `n2`. Si inicializas los valores `n1` y `n2` a cero, verás que el programa te muestra `0` como resultado.

Comment: Sí señor.Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Estas haciendo la suma antes de pasarle los numeros.
Lo unico que tienes que hacer es mover la operacion `int res=n1+n2;` dentro del ciclo while.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool cont = true;
    char seguir;
    short int n1;
    short int n2;

    while (cont) {
        cout << "Ingrese un número: " << endl;
        cin >> n1;

        cout << "Ingrese otro número: " << endl;
        cin >> n2;

        int res = n1 + n2;//operacion dentro del ciclo
        cout << "El resultado es: " << res << endl;

        cout << "¿Realizar otra suma?..." << endl;
        cin >> seguir;

        if (tolower(seguir) == 's') {//aceptara tanto S minuscula como mayuscula.
            cont = true;
        } else {
            cont = false;
        }
    }

    cout << "¡Hasta pronto!";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

La variable `res` y asignar la suma de dos valores de entrada. Lo que se imprimirá es un valor aleatorio que proviene de la memoria.

Para ayudar, declara la variable auxiliar `res` e inicialízala en `0`, luego úsala para almacenar la suma de los valores justo después de que las variables de entrada sean inicializadas.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool cont = true;
    char seguir;
    short int n1;
    short int n2;
    int res=0; // variable auxiliar.

    while (cont) {
        cout << "Ingrese un número: ";
        cin >> n1;

        cout << "Ingrese otro número: ";
        cin >> n2;

        res = n1 + n2; // almacena el valor de la suma de las dos entradas.
        cout << "El resultado es: " << res << endl;

        cout << "¿Realizar otra suma? (s/n): ";
        cin >> seguir;
        if (seguir != 's') {
            cont = false;
        }
    }

    cout << "¡Hasta pronto!";
    return 0;
}
```

Al declarar explícitamente que la variable res tendrá el valor cero, garantiza que no tendrá valores aleatorios de memoria.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Arar? No entiendo que quieres decir con eso. El resto de la respuesta está bien.

Comment: Fue un error de tipeo, muchas gracias por avisarme :(

Answer (score 2):

Estube mirando y otra alternativa a las respuesta ya existente seria hacerlo un poco más simple, claro incluyendo los datos que deben estar dentro del bucle:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char seguir;

    do {
        int n1, n2;

        std::cout << "Ingrese dos números separados por espacio: ";
        std::cin >> n1 >> n2;

        std::cout << "El resultado es: " << n1 + n2 << '\n';

        std::cout << "¿Realizar otra suma? (s/n): ";
        std::cin >> seguir;
    } while (seguir == 's' || seguir == 'S');

    std::cout << "¡Hasta pronto!";
    return 0;
}
```